# Django user save hook

Tags: django, django-admin

In the django admin, when a user is given superuser status, I wish to perform a check.
I want to see if the user email is from in the form of *.company.com

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If you add the user through the Django admin, can't you just look at the email? You shouldn't be adding superusers automatically.

Comment: Just to get it right, you want that the user who creates the new superuser has an email of a specific form, or that the entered email for the user who gets superuser permissions has this form?

Comment: @iyrag - I can look at the email, but I want to stop it programatically to avoid user errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def check_superuser(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):
    if sender is User and instance.is_superuser and not instance.email.endswith('@company.com'):
        ...

post_save.connect(check_superuser, sender=User)
```

So now, every time an instance of `User` is saved, it will run the above `check_superuser` method